# Only allow one audio element to play at a time

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I have multiple audio players, each with a play and stop button, on one page. The only issue I have is when you click one play button, and then another, they play on top of one another. Can someone help me with the code I would need to stop whatever song is playing when another play button is clicked - so there would never be more than one song playing at a time?? Thanks! Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
    })

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
    })
})


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#play-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].play();
    })

    $("#stop-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player1")[0].currentTime = 0;
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var allAudioEls = $('audio');

    function pauseAllAudio() {
       allAudioEls.each(function() {
          var a = $(this).get(0);
          a.pause();
       });
    }


    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        pauseAllAudio();
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
    })

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
    })

    $("#play-bt1").click(function(){
        pauseAllAudio();
        $("#audio-player1")[0].play();
    })

    $("#stop-bt1").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player1")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player1")[0].currentTime = 0;
    })
})
```

Comment: Ok, I tried substituting your code in and now none of the songs will play. Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: basically when you play an audio, this code previously pause all audio, then play the only one you've selected

Comment: I realize that is what it is supposed to do, but when I used your code, none of the songs will play to begin with. Is there possibly an error in the code - it doesn't seem to be working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, can I ask you one more thing...is there an easy way to change the code so when you click on play from song to song, it will always start from the beginning of the song - instead of pausing it where it left off when you clicked another play button?? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: yes, just add a.currenTime = 0 inside the function pauseAllAudio()

Comment: @icalderan Where exactly do you put the new JS file? How do you add it from the website editor? I'm using the `Advanced Code Editor` plugin, but i can't create new files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my php code

```
<div id="sourceplay"></div>
<table class="table tlm-table-epg">
                    <tbody>

                    <?php foreach (\common\models\Video::find()->orderBy('id desc')->all() as $valuevideo): ?>
                        <tr class="tlm-epg">
                            <td class="width35">
                                <a class="playbutton"
                                   values="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . $valuevideo->url ?>" tss="<?=$valuevideo->id?>"><i
                                          id="ts-<?=$valuevideo->id?>"  class="fa fa-play-circle-o font-size-25"></i></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <p><?= $valuevideo->name ?></p>
                                <p class="margin-top-10px"><?php $date = date_create_from_format('Ymd', $valuevideo->code);
                                    echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y'); ?></p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click','.playbutton',function () {
       var self=$(this);
       if(self.attr('class')!='playbutton actives'){
           var t = $(".fa.fa-pause-circle-o.font-size-25");
           var r = $("#ts-"+self.attr('tss'));
           var last = $(".playbutton.actives");
           $("#sourceplay").html('<audio controlsList="nodownload" id="mainpls" autoplay="true" controls="controls">' +
               '<source src="'+self.attr('values')+'" type="audio/mpeg" >' +
               '</audio>');
           t.attr('class','fa fa-play-circle-o font-size-25 actives');
           r.attr('class','fa fa-pause-circle-o font-size-25');
           self.attr('class','playbutton actives');
           last.attr('class','playbutton');
       }else {
           $("#mainpls").remove();
           var t = $(".fa.fa-pause-circle-o.font-size-25");
           var last = $(".playbutton.actives");
           t.attr('class','fa fa-play-circle-o font-size-25 actives');
           self.attr('class','playbutton');
           last.attr('class','playbutton');
       }
    })
})
```