# How to allow only one of several audio files to play on a page?

Tags: html, html5-audio

So, I'm going to have several audio files on one page.  I want to know how to make it so that only one song can play at the same time.  Right now, I can click "play" on all files and they all start playing.  Is there a way to make it such that if song1 is playing and I click "play" on song2, then song1 will stop playing?

Here is my basic code for 2 songs:

```
    <table>
                <tr>                       <!--Off The Grid-->
                    <td>Off The Grid</td>  
                    <td>                   <!--Audio File -->
                        <object width="200px" height="15px">
                            <param name="src" value="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3">
                            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                            <param name="controller" value="true">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
                            <embed src="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="75px" height="40px" controller="true" bgcolor="#ffffff"></embed>
                        </object>
                    </td>                  <!--End Audio File -->
                </tr>                      <!--End Off the Grid -->
                <tr>                       <!--Far-Sighted-->
                    <td>Far-Sighted</td>
                    <td>
                        <object width="200px" height="15px">
                            <param name="src" value="../audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3">
                            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                            <param name="controller" value="true">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
                            <embed src="../audio/far_sighted_michael_pitluk.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="75px" height="40px" controller="true" bgcolor="#ffffff"></embed>
                        </object>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Note: there is another question exactly like mine on here, but I don't understand the code at all.  Perhaps I need to learn that specific code.  Can someone tell me what the code language is? [Here is the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196979/only-allow-one-audio-element-to-play-at-a-time).  It seems I need to learn a scripting language or something to pull this off.

Comment: In fact, nearly all webpages with any non-strictly-documental feature today use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, to implement mutual exclusion for audio playback, you will need scripting.

The example you mentioned is in [JavaScript](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript&ei=yEvSUeOZI8zFiwKf44DQCw&usg=AFQjCNE49yezWbmoTEVjHqtFhe-qj85w7g&bvm=bv.48705608,d.cGE), but using the [jQuery](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http://jquery.com/&ei=ykvSUaGPIKHwiwLT34HoBQ&usg=AFQjCNFA7CZ5sWRDhHPuipmhL7zVksjC2A&bvm=bv.48705608,d.cGE) framework.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#play-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
    })

    $("#stop-bt").click(function(){
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $("#audio-player")[0].currentTime = 0;
    })
})
```

That code attaches a "document is ready parsing" [event handler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_handler). Within that handler, two click event handlers are attached to either "play" and "stop" buttons.

In short, it's a manually activated player. The solution below moves the "shut everything up" functionality to an independent function, called as needed.

Read more about [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM) and [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events). That is a pure DOM and JavaScript reference. To make things work with Internet Explorer (especially older versions), you will have to tweak some things yourself or (much easier), use jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, I don't know any scripting languages as I just learned html and css.  How would I go about learning to write the script for this?  Should I learn php or javascript?

Comment: PHP is a [server-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side) language. Useful, but not strictly needed for this. Do learn the basics of JavaScript and keep in mind that things in the HTML-and-JS world are essentially [event-driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). jQuery will make your life easier.